# Aptana Studio 3 Snippet Around Selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana, code-snippets, aptana3

So I have recently switched from `Dreamweaver` to `Aptana Studio 3` and I have been playing around with the whole custom snippet feature. For the life of me though I cannot figure out how to take a selection/highlighted text and wrap it with my own custom code and/or text. I have looked around the internet for three days now and cannot find anything regarding snippets. I have found some things using commands and key combinations, but I am wanting to create and use a snippet and trying to modify what I have found is not producing good fruit.

I have been able to create my own category and some basic snippets that insert straight text, but nothing that uses a selection.

I have absolutely NO experience with `Ruby` so forgive me if what follows is completely atrocious. I have more experience with `PHP`, `HTML`, `Javascript`, `Java`, etc. Here is what I have so far.

```
snippet "Selection Test" do |snip|
  snip.trigger = "my_code"
  snip.input = :selection
  selection = ENV['TM_SELECTED_TEXT'] || ''
  snip.expansion = "<test>$selection</test>\n"
  snip.category = "My Snippets"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with custom Snippets, but if it helps, there is an example in the HTML bundle of a snippet that surrounds the selected text with `<p></p>` tags when you do `Ctrl + Shift + W`. You can see the code for it in snippets.rb in the HTML bundle:

```
with_defaults :scope => 'text.html - source', :input => :none, :output =>    :insert_as_snippet do |bundle|
  command t(:wrap_selection_in_tag_pair) do |cmd|
    cmd.key_binding = "CONTROL+SHIFT+W"
    cmd.input = :selection
    cmd.invoke do |context|
      selection = ENV['TM_SELECTED_TEXT'] || ''
      if selection.length > 0
        "<${1:p}>${2:#{selection.gsub('/', '\/')}}</${1:p}>"
      else
        "<${1:p}>$0</${1:p}>"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I fiddled around with putting it into the PHP bundle for a few minutes under `CTRL + Shift + P` and got it working in HTML files, which was not my goal... but was progress. I may play around with it some more later, but in the meantime, maybe you know enough after all of your research to get something put together. I would be interested to see your results if you get this figured out.

Comment: Yes, the example you gave is very similar to what I have found on the internet, but this uses key combinations. I was looking for a way to write a snippet that you just click on from a list on the left like the other snippets. The code I provided was my attempt at modifying what I found on the internet, but to use snippets instead of key combinations. However, it is easy to tell that I wasn't very successful and modifying the code to work as a snippet.

Comment: I see what you are saying. From what I understand, Snippets can't use selections, only Commands can. Commands are not listed in the Snippets view, they are under Commands (and can be accessed with key combos). I thought maybe you could make a Snippet that called a Command, but the only examples I could find only went the other way (Commands calling Snippets). This makes sense because Snippets are typically called by typing out something (like 'php') and Ctrl + Space transforms it into the Snippet. A selection doesn't make sense here since you couldn't have anything selected while you type.